# Set-Cookie head on a POST request 302 redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios to try and login to the COD website to get the XSRF token for authenticating requests in Node.

I've been able to login fine, however when inspecting the traffic in Chrome, I can see the page I call below returns a 302 redirect, but in the headers, includes all of the set-cookie headers that contain the XSRF tokens I need to capture

```
const loginReq = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://profile.callofduty.com/do_login?new_SiteId=cod",
    data: `username=foo&remember_me=true&password=bar%21&_csrf=${csrf}`,
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.102 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.0.1309.37",
        "Referer": "https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/login?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.callofduty.com%2F",
        "Origin": "https://profile.callofduty.com",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Cookie": cookie.join(';')
    }
});
```

[image]

The issue I have is that my Axios response returns a 200 and my headers are not that from the page as I would expect.  Instead I get

```
{ 'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
  server: 'Apache/2.4.39 (Amazon) Communique/4.2.2',
  'last-modified': 'Thu, 12 Mar 2020 00:37:41 GMT',
  etag: 'W/"785b9-5a09d8f80f9a5-gzip"',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=217372',
  expires: 'Thu, 19 Mar 2020 00:37:37 GMT',
  date: 'Mon, 16 Mar 2020 12:14:45 GMT',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close, Transfer-Encoding',
  'x-activision-regioncode': 'EN',
  'x-activision-countrycode': 'GB',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://profile.callofduty.com' }
```

Does anyone know how I can capture the set-cookie headers I require?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding the following to my axios object:

```
        maxRedirects: 0,
        validateStatus: function (status) {
            return status >= 200 && status < 303; // default
        },
```